# Не печатаемые символы в заголовке окна eclipse (DBeaver)

Tags: java, eclipse, шрифты

Не печатаемые символы в заголовке окна eclipse, на скриншоте. Локаль ru_RU.UTF8. Webdings и windings шрифты установлены для убунту - не знаю надо ли ещё как то их доустанавливать для явы, и не знаю нужные ли шрифты поставил или проблема не в этом. Версия явы openjdk-8 из репозиториев ubuntu17.10. Так же пробовал на oracle-8-jre.

В редакторе все символы отображаются.

Искал вопросы и гуглил на эту тему.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Каким-то образом в настройках подключения в концы строк (имя БД, имя таблицы и т.д.) попали символы `\n`. Возможно, как следствие copy/paste из консоли или откуда-то ещё.

Comment: Ну тогда и фиг с ними, я думал это какие-то другие символы. Спасибо за ответ.